# Is use strict creating a issue, DOM is not updating only for template with replace true

Tags: angularjs

```
'use strict';
angular.module('$praveen.directives').directive('currentTime',
    function () {
        return function (scope, elem, attr) {
            elem.html("Hello");
        }
    });
```

i am using the above code but DOM is not updating.

Comment: No using strict is not creating an issue